# Changing password issues

Tags: php, mysqli

Can't figure out the problem. The problems start with ** and end with **, with the problem line right after it. Please help me fix my code, seems like there are too many issues. Very sorry.

```
   <?php
    include 'core/login.php'; 
    include 'core/init.php';    
    include 'includes/head.php';    
    if(count($_POST)>0) {
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT *from users WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]) 
    {
          mysqli_query("UPDATE users set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "' WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
          $message = "Password Changed";
    } 
    else 
          $message = "Current Password is not correct";
    }
```

?>

Errors I am getting are:

```
expects 2 parameters, 1 given / 1 parameter to be mysqli result, null given
undefined variable result
undefined currentpassword
undefined new password / expects 2 parameters, 1 given
```

Comment: in your mysqli query try adding the connection settinsg `mysqli_query($connection,$query)`

Comment: Use prepared statements and crypt your passwords >.<

Comment: There is no space in the select, between `*` and `from`: `*from`

Comment: Tried this but doesn't work   $result = mysqli_query($link, $query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'"));

Answer (score 1):

The mysqli_query function expects the first parameter to be a MySQLi link identifier. In your code, the first parameter is an SQL statement (i.e. a string).

A link identifier is returned by the function mysqli_connect(), which you probably used in your init.php script.

Example:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "info");
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

Comment: Is it hard to write out how is should look like? BTW, undefined confirmpasword and new password fixed.

Comment: @Anthony You will need to show me the code that uses mysqli_connect as I don't know the name of the variable that stores your link identifier.

Comment: <?php
 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "info");
   
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
 
    die("Could not connect to database");
 
}
   
 
 ?>

Comment: @Anthony Update my example. By the way, you should pay attention to David's answer as your code is vulnerable and you're not storing your passwords in a secure manner.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by reading the error message:

> expects 2 parameters, 1 given / 1 parameter to be mysqli result, null given

So the function expects 2 parameters.  And you supply it with...

```
mysqli_query("SELECT *from users WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'")
```

one parameter.  `mysqli_query()` needs to be given the connection object as well:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT *from users WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'")
```

(or whatever your connection object is named)

> undefined variable result

The operation which created `$result` failed, so anything which uses `$result` will also fail.

> undefined currentpassword

This suggests that the POST data doesn't contain the value you're looking for.  You can use `isset()` to determine if a value exists before trying to use it.

> undefined new password / expects 2 parameters, 1 given

Same problem(s) as above.

Also, there are two more problems you're not noticing...

```
"UPDATE users set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "' WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'"
```

1. Your code is ***wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)***.
2. You are ***storing [user passwords in plain text](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)***.

Both of these are ***extremely bad things*** and should be fixed immediately.

Comment: Note sure how to fix it, but thank you very much for the HEADS UP!

Answer (score 0):

Your `mysqli_query` is incorrect, it wants a second parameter, the connection string. Try something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");

mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *from users WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this code...Only problem now is that it is not changing. At least errors are gone, now will just play with it.

```
<?php
    include 'core/login.php'; 
    include 'core/init.php';    
    include 'includes/head.php';    
    if(count($_POST)>0) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *from users WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($_POST["currentpassword"] == $row["password"]) {
    mysqli_query("UPDATE users set password='" . $_POST["newpassword"] . "' WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
    $message = "Password Changed";
    } else $message = "Current Password is not correct";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to loop over your query with a `while`. Replace `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);` with  `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){...}` - Plus, you shouldn't be accepting an answer if it doesn't solve the problem 100%.

Comment: Got it, just helped that was it, then again all did, fixed. Thank you Fred